# Favicon not showing in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, favicon

I've searched all over the internet already and I still don't know why  the favicon wont show on safari, it shows ok on chrome and FF, 
I've tried these in the header:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

or this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?23189123" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

changed the favicon to  32 bits, or removed the WebpageIcons.db from safari library etc.
and I check the website on browserstacks in case is my cache..

Is there anything else Im missing? please let me know any suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do a clean refresh. Your browser is in the cache!

Comment: Also make sure fav icon image is there in correct path.. As C-link Nepal said, clear browser cache..

Comment: I've checked the site on browserstack in case it's my cache, do you think  browserstacks could be cached too? (im thinking it will refresh  from time to time)

The favicon is located in /site, so I'm sure  the path is correct, also pointed the file in the header.

Comment: resave your favicon as an 8bit (256color) and re-upload to your site. This may help.

Comment: Worked!, My computer was heavily cashed, not even removing the cache or using  browserstacks / incognito view will let me  see the favicon (all of them were cashed). So i used another pc and it was working fine in all browsers. Thanks everyone.

Comment: did you check this [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3939787?tstart=0)?

Answer (score 8):

Safari uses "apple-touch-icon" and not just "icon". Also, you will have to specify the icon for all Apple devices if you want it to show up in all of them.

Read more here https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use https://favicon.io/ and generate the html code snippet and file set using your image for favicon.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem where the favicon wasn't appearing in Safari during the development of a Next.js project on my Ubuntu machine. I discovered a solution that addressed this issue, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68925887/11900235) for local development.

Moreover, to ensure the favicon displays correctly in live environments, such as staging or production, I had to make an additional configuration. I added the attribute `crossorigin="use-credentials"` as recommended in [this](https://medium.com/@aurelien.delogu/401-error-on-a-webmanifest-file-cb9e3678b9f3) guide.