# Why does safari show favicon on interior pages but not on my root domain?

Tags: html, safari

So I'm trying to add a custom favicon for this domain using the bare minimum tag of

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="https://cdns3.flysumo.com/media/28983/conversions/642ae694c2fe4_favicon-primary.png">
```

This works on my interior pages (https://client.pugpie.com/dogs) but does not work on the root domain of (https://client.pugpie.com/)

I'm testing this just by simply looking at my tab on safari. This works fine in chrome btw.

Comment: is this not a duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68885882/favicon-not-displaying-on-safari

Comment: not quite since my question is about a discrepancy between safari top level domain and interior page. His question is about his working in chrome but not safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has to do with caching on the browser. Testing this using new machines were not affected. Looks like just one png favicon is required.