# Favicon not showing up on Safari 17.2.1

Tags: safari, favicon

The favicon for my website is broken on Safari (17.2.1) but works on all other browsers. This is how it looks like:
[image]

I have already tried to empty the cache from Safari directly & delete the whole favicon cache folder and restart Safari. Nothing seems to work.

Here is my folder of favicon images. I have checked they are accessible, i.e. I can go to website/favicon.ico and actually see the favicon.

[image]

Here is my meta data that is used in the html header:

```
    <Head>
        <title>Dataleap</title>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="application-name" content="Dataleap" />
        <meta name="description" content="Market Research simplified" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png" />
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="48x48" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />

        <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `
    // We pre-filled your app ID in the widget URL: 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/sx115hzn'
    (function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',w.intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments);};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args);};w.Intercom=i;var l=function(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/sx115hzn';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);};if(document.readyState==='complete'){l();}else if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})();
`
            }}
        />
    </Head>
```

Do you know how to fix it or further debug the issue?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895792/22799014). Maybe your `mask-icon` needs to be an `.ico` instead of an `.svg`?

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work. What I have found out is that if I delete the safari cache, then the favicon is displayed correctly. As soon as I restart the browser it's gone again and then doesn't come back.